# how to move down 1 row for every loop until cell empty

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

How do I move down 1 row for every loop until cell empty in column A?

I need to start on Row 5 copy to another workbook then loop to the next row (Row6) until contents are empty.

Here is my code

```
    Sub Macro3()
'''
Do

''GRAB A ROW
    Windows("theFILE2.working.xlsm").Activate
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\New folder\OVERVIEW TEMPLATE(macro edition)(current).xlsm"
    Windows("OVERVIEW TEMPLATE(macro edition)(current).xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("LISTS").Select
    Rows("4:4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Windows("OVERVIEW TEMPLATE(macro edition)(current).xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("PLANT OVERVIEW").Select

''SAVE AS
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim FileName2 As String


    FileName1 = Range("N1").Value
    FileName2 = Range("A1").Value

    Path = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The FILES\theFILES\" & FileName1 & "\"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

Loop

End Sub
```

Thankyou in advanced!

Comment: Hi Kenny, I saw your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066796/creating-multiple-workbooks-from-one-workbook-vba), so I'm wondering if you can clarify what you're trying to do? Generally, when you're copying from one sheet to another, the order is something like this: 1) Open the source sheet 2) Open the destination sheet (where you're copying to) 3) Use a Loop to copy information from one sheet to the other 4) Save the destination sheet and optionally close it. Are you just interested in copying from one sheet to the other, or are you trying to do something with each line?

Comment: thanks for your interest. for the line "Rows("5:5").Select" I would like the loop function to move down to the next row. I am taking the info from each line to create a new workbook which then the Save As function will have the values for the save.

Comment: thanks for your interest. for the line "Rows("5:5").Select" I would like the loop function to move down to the next row. I am taking the info from each line to create a new workbook which then the Save As function will have the values for the save. After the SaveAs finishes i need it to repeat for the next line. I hope I am explaining this correctly. (I am new to this site, obviously, and ran out of time on the previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're new to VBA, and there are some concepts you're picking up pretty quickly. Recording macros in Excel is a great way to find out how you could do something in Excel. However, there are some drawbacks to the way Excel does it also. Here are a few concepts that will help:

1. **Don't** use *Selection*, *ActiveCell*, *ActiveSheet*, *Select*, *Activate*, etc. unless you absolutely have to. I know that's what the Macro Recorder in Excel does, but if you don't do it exactly right, it can cause errors, especially when you start working with multiple workbooks!

   Much better to assign an *object*, and use that object to do what you want to do. In the code below, I assigned the *Workbooks* and *worksheets* to objects and used those to get stuff done. *Ranges* are also common objects to use.
2. Related to that, make sure to always **fully qualify your objects**. For example, you can write code like this: `Var1 = Cells(1, 1).Value` but it will get the value from cell A1 in the *Active Worksheet*, not necesarily the worksheet or workbook you intended. Much better to write it this way: `Var1 = wksSource.Cells(1, 1).Value`  I did specify a sheet name "Sheet1" for your source workbook - **change it** to the actual name of the sheet you're copying *from*.
3. I assigned the most common strings to **Constants** at the top. There's a balance between assigning every string to a constant and using only in-line strings (for example, some might assign the sheet names like "LISTS" to a constant), but if they're only used once and in a prominent place, I don't worry about assigning a constant for it. But especially when the value is used multiple places, a constant makes it easier for when you want to re-use the code for a similar task. I also put a constant in there for the Source Path, although that's not required if the workbook is already open.
4. I also declared all the variables at the top - some languages and programmers do it differently, but I like to be able to see what's being used at the beginning.
5. Notice the **While** specifier on your *Do ... Loop*. This will only loop while there is a value in the first column of the current row.

Here's how I would write the code for your task:

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim FileName2 As String
    Dim FullFileName As String

    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim wksDest2 As Worksheet

    Const scWkbSourcePath As String = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\"        ' For example
    Const scWkbSourceName As String = "theFILE2.working.xlsm"
    Const scWkbDest1Path As String = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The_FILES\New_folder\"
    Const scWkbDest1Name As String = "OVERVIEW TEMPLATE_macro edition_current_.xlsm"
    Const scWkbDest2Path As String = "D:\folder1\folder2\Projects\The_FILES\theFILES\"

    Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
    Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")      ' Replace Sheet1 with the sheet name
    SourceRow = 5
    DestRow = 4

Do While wksSource.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Value <> ""
    ' Open the template workbook
    Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open(scWkbSourcePath & scWkbDest1Name)
    Set wksDest = wkbDest.Sheets("LISTS")

''COPY A ROW
    wksSource.Rows(SourceRow).Copy Destination:=wksDest.Rows(DestRow)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With wksDest.Rows(DestRow).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    wkbDest.Activate
    Set wksDest2 = wkbDest.Sheets("PLANT OVERVIEW")

''SAVE AS
    FileName1 = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace( _
        Replace(wksDest2.Range("N1").Value _
        , ".", "_") _
        , "/", "_") _
        , "\", "_") _
        , "?", "_") _
        , "|", "_") _
        , "<", "_") _
        , ">", "_") _
        , ":", "_") _
        , "*", "_") _
        , """", "_")
    FileName2 = wksDest2.Range("A1").Value

    Path = scWkbDest2Path & FileName1 & "\"
    If Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Path
    End If
    FullFileName = Path & FileName2 & ".xlsx"
    wkbDest.SaveAs Filename:=FullFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wkbDest.Close

    ' Best practice to set objects to Nothing before re-using an object variable
    Set wksDest = Nothing
    Set wksDest2 = Nothing
    Set wkbDest = Nothing

    ' Move down 1 row for source sheet
    SourceRow = SourceRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

#### Edit

Some notes and things I learned regarding Folder and File name characters:

- Although parentheses *can* be used in filenames, I wasn't able to get your original filename to save - but removing the parentheses solved the problem.
- Since you're creating file and folder names from (potentially dirty) data, you should clean up (remove or replace with **_**) the characters that can't be used in those names: **\** **/** **|** **?** **<** **>** **:** ***** **"**
- I found this on a Microsoft page for [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period.

- Although it is allowed inside a file name, a full stop (**.**) cannot be the last char of a folder name, which is generally where you find it in a text string. Besides, it can be confusing and occasionally cause problems *within* a file name, so I'd recommend replacing them all.

  - The Trim() function can be used to remove spaces *at the end of a folder name*. Be aware that within the string, it also changes multiple spaces in a row to a single space.
- Especially since you're creating folders from data, you need to make sure the folder exists before saving a file to it. **MkDir** is the command for this.
- If your template workbook isn't open when you start, you may need to specify the path as well in the Open() statement.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, and I do like the organization.

Comment: I have a question about the     "Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open(scWkbDest1Name)" as the error compiler states the workbook is not there when it is. On another note what does the "sc" represent in your though process for all the Constants?

Comment: Solved my previous comment by changing "Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open(scWkbDest1Name)" to "Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open(scWkbDest1Path & scWkbDest1Name)"  & "Set wksDest = wkbSource.Sheets("LISTS")" to "Set wksDest = wkbDest.Sheets("LISTS")" now I have the 1st wkbk filled out & saved correct.

Comment: Next Q, which was my original question on this thread was the Loop function. I see "SourceRow = 5" which seams correct but on the Loop the Error Compiler states a problem on "wksSource.Rows(SourceRow).Copy Destination:=wksDest.Rows(DestRow)". I notice one of the last lines states "SourceRow = SourceRow + 1" but as the code loops around again source is then reprogramed to "SourceRow = 5". Is this the problem? I read about the "i" variable, I haven't used this before & not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Ah, I always forget that VBA treats Rows differently than Excel does. Use `wksSource.Rows(SourceRow).Cells.Copy`. I'm not sure but you may need to use `.Cells` after `wksDest.Rows(DestRow)` also.  For `SourceRow = 5`, the code will only loop back up to the `Do While` line, so it shouldn't be resetting it to 5. If you step through the code using F8, the 2nd time thru the loop, if you hover over `SourceRow` in the *Copy* line, it should show a value of `6`.

Comment: I see 'SourceRow = 5' does show a value of 6 on the 2nd Loop when I hover over using F8.. But still as I come down to 'wksSource.Rows(SourceRow).Cells.Copy Destination:=wksDest.Rows(DestRow)' I am still compiling an "Run time Error 91", even if I use 'wksSource.Rows(SourceRow).Cells.Copy Destination:=wksDest.Rows(DestRow).Cells'

Comment: I posted updated code in the answer. Don't have time now, but later will add some explanation and discoveries.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I figured out why I was running into the error 91 situation and solved like you edited your answer by moving the     set wkbdest    and.     Set wksdest     below the    Do While line. I then ran into the special/unaccepted characters for the save which I manually (advanced searched) found and replaced. Thanks for showing me how to write such code.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. I did clean up the code a little bit more (especially replacing chars in file names and testing for a folder before creating it) and added some commentary about folder and file names. I do have to say, you pick this up quick for someone just starting with VBA!

Comment: Thankyou for all the help. I posted another question i could use your help on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450915/how-can-i-only-copy-visible-cells-from-a-table-using-this-vba